# GT 710 Overclocking

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, graphics-card, framerate

I have a DDR3 GT 710 2GB Passive Edition from ZOTAC. As you all might already know, it is not ideal for gaming. Hence, I intend on overclocking it to gain a couple of frames for GTA 5 (gives about 35 max, drops down to 11 occasionally). I have read many articles online about how it is a low end card, which means that it has pretty high overclocking headroom, but mine seems to hit the dead-end at just about 100 to the core clock and 250 to the memory clock, which give me no gains. Any reasons as to why this is the case and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

Low end cards do not have high overclocking headroom.  Pretty much every GPU within a given series uses the same basic silicon, and then gets binned based on performance.  Your card is a low end card because it performed so poorly in the binning tests.  Cores were disabled, the clock was limited, etc. because of defects in the silicon.  Trying to unlock those cores or push the clock speed will just lead to instability.

The only real option you have is to get a better GPU.  If budget is a consideration, you might be able to find a used GTX 1080Ti or GTX 1650Ti or similar for relatively cheap.  Even a GTX 970 would be a vast improvement.  However, since you haven't said what the rest of your system is, it's impossible to tell if you would hit other bottlenecks, such as because of your CPU.

Comment: i3 6100 - CPU
4GB 2133Mhz (SK Hynix) Single Channel - RAM

Comment: You're probably currently bottlenecked by your RAM.  8GB of dual channel RAM _could_ go a long way to more stable framerates, although that is unlikely to improve your peak framerates.  If you want a better experience (60+ FPS, higher quality, etc.), you're going to need a new computer; everything needs upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment the OP left on an answer:

> i3 6100 - CPU 4GB 2133Mhz (SK Hynix) Single Channel - RAM

Your hardware is really scraping the lower end of the system requirements for GTA V. You can find details on these system requirements at https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/203428177/Grand-Theft-Auto-V-PC-System-Requirements, but to summarize, while your i3 might be enough based on online comments and videos, the 4 GB of RAM is really low, especially considering it's single channel. It appears that if you upgrade your RAM to 8 GB dual channel memory, that could probably help improve the lower end of your framerate. Then for your GPU, a 1050 can get you to a stable 1080p60, as shown in this video:

I recommend that you search YouTube for benchmark videos for the hardware you're interested in and see if anything in that manner strikes you as acceptable. For context:

is a video of your current setup.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I'm not really planning on upgrading my potato, as I'm going to be purchasing a decent laptop sometime soon. I just wanted to see if there is something that I can do to make it better without spending a penny, but the chances look bleak.